# How to use capistrano to deploy a Rails app with bun for js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Title says it all. I have an app that's been using esbuild to this point without issues, and I can successfully run bun in development with no problems.

I've logged in to my Ubuntu 20.04 server as the deploy user and installed bun with:

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

I can then run bun successfully:

```
$ bun -v
# => 1.0.13
```

But the capistrano deploy fails with:

```bash
cssbundling-rails: Command install failed, ensure bun is installed
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the bun installer adds lines to the user's `.bashrc` that puts the bun bin (type that three times fast...) on the user's path. But the majority of the `.bashrc` doesn't run in the non-interactive capistrano login.

The solution is to add this in the `config/deploy.rb`:

```rb
set :default_env, { path: "~/.bun/bin:$PATH" }
```